# MySQL select count(*) function to find all status with OPEN

Tags: mysql, database, select, count

I'm stuck in my code!

In my db, I have these columns:

> id | name | mail | status | date

in `status` it can only be OPEN or CLOSED.

Now I have more then 100 rows in my db and want to find out how many are **OPEN** and how many are **CLOSED**, but I cant figure out how to do this.

I've tried to write a lot of post here at the page, but no one is getting me the right answer.

I wrote this code:

```
$query = "SELECT status, COUNT(OPEN) FROM cases GROUP BY status ORDER BY COUNT(status) desc";
$result = mysql_query($query);


<?php echo($result); ?>
```

Now I hoped to get the result like this:

> 53

Comment: how do you want the output in a single row with label as open & closed?

Comment: My main idea was to make 2 .php documents and include them in two different boxes ..

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check if it works for you

Comment: You really should stop using `Mysql_` functions as they're now deprecated and insecure, you should instead use `mysqli_` or `pdo` connections to your SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) method of mysql to check the status

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Open', SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Closed' FROM cases
```

Let me know if it works for you

> In PHP

```
<?php 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
  }
  $sql="SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Open', SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Closed' FROM cases"; 
  if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   // Return the number of rows in result set 
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    printf("%d",$rowcount); // Free result set
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($result); 
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

> IN HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
  <div class="circle-tile">
    <a href="#"><div class="circle-tile-heading green"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-fw fa-3x"></i></div></a>
    <div class="circle-tile-content green">
      <div class="circle-tile-description text-faded"> Åbne sager</div>
      <div class="circle-tile-number text-faded "><?php echo $row['OPEN'];?></div>
      <a class="circle-tile-footer" href="#">Mere info <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
  <div class="circle-tile ">
    <a href="#"><div class="circle-tile-heading red"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw fa-3x"></i></div></a>
    <div class="circle-tile-content red">
      <div class="circle-tile-description text-faded"> Lukket sager </div>
      <div class="circle-tile-number text-faded "><?php echo $row['CLOSED'];?></div>
      <a class="circle-tile-footer" href="#">Mere Info <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This return the number 1 - That is far away from how many rows I have in my DB

Comment: I got two options in a dropdown with ÅBEN and LUKKET translation from danish to English OPEN and CLOSED cases is the table

Comment: @KennethFroschKanneKallesen Check this fiddle. Its returning correct output http://rextester.com/GXC25279

Comment: It kinda do the job, I assume it's my php code that makes the muck up right now :(

Comment: if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Open', SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Closed' FROM cases";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("%d",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: Now I get this: 1Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )

Comment: Ahhhh!!! this will return in numeric format, if you need column names, you can use `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row($result)`; My bad. let me update the answer

Comment: Now we have something! Now to the end, can I do so, that the result can go into 2 diff. boxes? 

Box1=ALL OPEN CASES 

Box2=ALL CLOSED CASES?

Comment: I've posted my HTML/PHP code - How to "clip" the string?

Comment: It returns 1 outside the boxes :)

Comment: Yes I used it, I think it's the "printf" function that giving the 1 outside the box, and show nothing in the boxes.

Comment: Yeah, and I get this one: Array ( [Open] => 2 [Closed] => 3 )in the same box.

Comment: Hurray! Now you are my hero of the day! :) Now I can go on to the next part of my code :) THANKS alot Champ!

Comment: Also. If you like the answer, please upvote it as well :)

Comment: note `sum(CASE WHEN status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` will return null instead of 0 if there are no rows matching the where conditions if you have`where`, which is probably not what you want. So I recommend using `COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`

Answer (score 1):

If `in status it can only be OPEN og(or?) CLOSED`, then this query gives you maximum 2 rows, with count of both statuses.

```
select count(*) as cnt, status from t group by status
```

Comment: At the end, I'll have two boxes, one with the amout of how many rows in my DB have the status CLOSED and another one with OPEN :)

Comment: @KennethFroschKanneKallesen  -  So, this query gives you what you need? or not?

Comment: Nope - I'm not getting my what I need.

Comment: @KennethFroschKanneKallesen - Then what you mean when you said:  `want to find out how many is OPEN and how many is CLOSED in status` ?

Comment: name| email | status | and so on ...
John| @.com|OPEN|
Joe  | @       | CLOSED| 
Jonny| @|  OPEN  |
Jens | @ | CLOSED |

Now my code should end up like this:

There are <?php echo($result_OPEN); ?> OPEN cases
There are <?php echo($result_CLOSED); ?> CLOSED cases

Answer (score 1):

try this its work for you

```
 $sql="SELECT status, COUNT() as count FROM cases WHERE status = 'ÅBEN' UNION ALL SELECT status, COUNT() FROM cases WHERE status = 'LUKKET'";
```

Comment: select count(*),  status from cases group by status; <-- This one is getting me the number 2, that is not my idea :) I'll get a number of ALL rows with the status of OPEN and all with CLOSED :)

Comment: try above two query it's give you output which you want

Comment: Sorry to say, but this giving my ERROR 500 in my browser.
Can it be because of the language is Danish words, and not english?

Comment: did you put ; after query ??

Comment: This is my code right now: 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT status, COUNT(*) as count FROM cases WHERE status = "ÅBEN"
UNION ALL
SELECT 'close', COUNT(*) FROM cases WHERE status = "LUKKET"";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("%d",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: i will check and inform you

Comment: $sql="SELECT status, COUNT() as count FROM cases WHERE status = 'ÅBEN' UNION ALL SELECT status, COUNT() FROM cases WHERE status = 'LUKKET'";

Comment: replace this with your code @KennethFroschKanneKallesen

Comment: Yeah, now my error 500 is gone, but still nothing number to show me 43 is open, and 57 is closed :(

Comment: check this query in mysql . its work in mysql or not ??

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
  <div class="circle-tile">
    <a href="#"><div class="circle-tile-heading green"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-fw fa-3x"></i></div></a>
    <div class="circle-tile-content green">
      <div class="circle-tile-description text-faded"> Åbne sager</div>
      <div class="circle-tile-number text-faded ">HERE TO INCLUDE ALL OPEN CASES</div>
      <a class="circle-tile-footer" href="#">Mere info <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
  <div class="circle-tile ">
    <a href="#"><div class="circle-tile-heading red"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw fa-3x"></i></div></a>
    <div class="circle-tile-content red">
      <div class="circle-tile-description text-faded"> Lukket sager </div>
      <div class="circle-tile-number text-faded ">HERE TO INCLUDE ALL CLOSED CASES</div>
      <a class="circle-tile-footer" href="#">Mere Info <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, just change `status` to the name of the column of the statuses:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM cases WHERE status = "OPEN"
```

Comment: And the PHP code should look like this: 

<?php
include('db.php');

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM cases WHERE status = "OPEN";"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

mysqli_close($con);
?>

SOME HTML

<?php echo($result); ?>

Comment: Disregard `;`, it's just a habit of mine